# Как хранить в Dll библиотеке форму (реализация на C++)

Tags: windows, c++, dll

Вопрос, как сохранить в dll окно и вызвать его оттуда? На языке С++ создать и вызвать. Дайте ссылку с объяснением или готовый код или исходник.

Comment: Это MFC или WinAPI?

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку в вопросе упоминается форма и C++, видимо, речь идет об MFC. Если так, то пойдут [extension DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20ytt2wa.aspx). [Пример работы](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=vcsamplesmfc&DownloadId=9723) с Extension DLL. Если это чистый Windows API, то так: [creating a window from a dll](http://sim0n.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/c-creating-a-window-from-a-dll/).